# How to denote the limit of a function with a vector input?

Tags: limits, notation, vectors

Suppose that I  have a function $y(v)$ such that $v \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{v \to 0} y(v) = \infty$.

How would I use the limit notation if $v$ is instead a vector $V = (v_1,v_2,..,v_N)$. That is, how would I denote that the limit of $y(V)$ is infinity as $V \in \mathbb{R}^N$ tends to $0$ (or the origin) because all of its components $v_i$ tend to $0$.

Do I have to do something like this: $\lim_{v_i \to 0} y(v_i) = \infty$ for all $i \in[1,..,N]$.

Comment: Is $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, $y(V):\mathbb{R}^N → \mathbb{R}$. Thanks

Comment: Then $\lim_{V\to 0} y(V) = \infty$ is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write $lim_{V \to 0}{y(V)}$, since the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined to be the vector whose components are 0. In general, you would write $lim_{(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \to (y_1, \cdots, y_n)}{f(a_1, \cdots, a_n)}$.

Comment: Thanks. On a side note, if I wanted to say that the limit of the first derivative of this function is equal to infinity when $V→0$, this would not make sense because the derivative of a vector valued function is defined in partials. So I would have to say $\lim_{v_i \to 0} ∂Y/∂v_i = \infty$ for all $i \in [1,...,N]$. Is this correct?